# Indicate that a LESS file should not be compiled on save

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013, less, web-essentials

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 with latest Web Essentials. I chose to partition my CSS into separate LESS files, and create a `build.less` which includes all my stuff. Now when I edit and save for example `tables.less`, Web Essentials will automatically compile it, adding a lot of "junk" css files to my web project.

I would like to exlude all of my LESS files from compilation except for the `build.less` one. Of course I know that as a side effect I have to always do a dummy `CTRL-S` on my `build.less`, but that's a fair tradeoff for being able to structure my code.

I've checked all of the options of WE related to LESS compilation without success till now. Are there any "hidden" tricks or some LESS preprocessor directives to make it work this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the file to start with an `_`.

Comment: Wow, that works like a charm. Where are such tricks documented? I guess I missed something somewhere.

Comment: WebEssentials is somewhat underdocumented